# Django Tastypie ModelResource : To Update Data Using Json format

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm new in django tastypie modelresource. This is my code to update data using tastypie. How to write a code in correct way using method PUT.

```
class OrderAerialStatusResources(ModelResource):
    user_id = fields.CharField(attribute='user_id')

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'

    class Meta:
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get','put']
        resource_name = 'order_status'
        authorization = Authorization()
        fields = ['id','status']

        filtering = {
            "id": ALL,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer

...

class Meta:
  queryset = Order.objects.all()
  resource_name = 'order_status'
  authorization = Authorization()
  fields = ['id','status']
  serializer = Serializer(formats=['json',])
  list_allowed_methods = ['put',]
  detail_allowed_methods = ['put',]
  filtering = {
      "id": ALL,
  }
```

Comment: I have already tried your code and i get this error 400 BAD REQUEST
"error": "Invalid data sent."

Comment: What data did you sent and Can you show me more console output of your browser?

Comment: this is my data:   { "status": 40 } and this is my url localhost:8000/rest/v1/order_status/?id=2

Comment: Change your data to { "status": 40, "id": 2}.

Comment: You data is Invalid, you need to send data that fit back into the data model on the server side. 
And before save Order instance into database, you can use [hydrate-cycle](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#the-hydrate-cycle) to prepare your data.

Comment: What do you use in front-end? I'm using angular.$resource to warp tastypie-api. And what your Order model looks like?

Comment: class BaseOrder(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
            verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='user_aerial_order')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CODES, default=PROCESSING,
            verbose_name=_('Status'))
    order_subtotal = CurrencyField(verbose_name=_('Order subtotal'))
    order_total = CurrencyField(verbose_name=_('Order Total'))
    cart_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Cart primary key'), blank=True, null=True)

Comment: Did you set field order.order_subtotal and order.order_total? Because it seems can't set None or ''.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104357/discussion-between-nuriffah-and-simonshyu).